# Which GitHub Meta IPs should be used to allow git clone?

Tags: github

I have a host which is access restricted and I want to whitelist git IP ranges to allow "git clone". I checked out https://api.github.com/meta and read https://developer.github.com/v3/meta/

I want to allow:

`git clone https://github.com/sahilsareen/LoveIsInTheAir.git`

Which IP addresses list obtained from https://api.github.com/meta should I whitelist?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you call the [GitHub Meta API](https://developer.github.com/v3/meta/), you will get a similar list.

Try first whitelisting the IPs from the `git` section: they are the ones for accessing the Git repositories you want to clone.

> `git`:
>
> An Array of IP addresses in CIDR format specifying the Git servers for GitHub.com.